# Convert Literal Text to Formula

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, excel-indirect

Using MS Excel 2010: I used the CONCATENATE formula to create a text string that looks like a formula and need a formula that will convert the text string to a formula; without the use of MS Excel Paste Special function or VBA/Macro.

Example: In Cell B2:G2 contains text, in Cell B4 I have CONCATENATE text formula that returns a text string

```
=TRIM(CONCATENATE(B2&" "&C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2&" "&G2&" "&H2))
```

I want Excel to interpret this string as a formula and return/show the value in Cell B6 as:    "Always be yourself … do not go out and look for a successful personality and duplicate it.” - Bruce Lee

[image]

I have attempted using the `INDIRECT` formula and without success, not certain if it's my formula or if it's possible.  SAMPLE: Cell B6:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B4"))
```

Comment: a) You are not using the [CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/concatenate-function-870e82a1-d47d-440e-9a77-23e7639eda1d) correctly. b) I don't think that the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) will do what you are asking of it.

Comment: @Jeeped is right. You are not concatenating anything, because (B2&" "&C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2&" "&G2&" "&H2) allready is a concatenated string. This is the correct way: =CONCATENATE(B2," ",C2," ",D2," ",E2," ",F2," ",G2," ",H2)

Comment: CONCATENATE and "&" are the same thing.  You do one or the other.  what you have done, is combined all your text first using the &, then asked the concatenate function to combine a single string into a single string.

Comment: do a search on the function EVALUATE.  you cant call it like you can other functions by just dropping it in a formula in the spreadsheet but you can call it in a named range.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the indirect function. I had been working with large database where I need to use vlookup function based on date. Every time I had to edit date manually in vlookup formula. But with use of indirect function now I can simply use work more faster using indirect function converting date to text and using in vlookup formula. Many many thanks to all who explained that indirect function converts text to formula.

Answer (score 3):

1)  CONCATENATE and & are the same thing.  In other words the formula you wrote as a string could be translated as:

```
=TRIM(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(B2)," "),C2)," "),D2)," "),E2)," "),F2)," "),G2)," "),H2))
```

If you are going to write out CONCATENATE for you function, then separate all he strings you want joined together as with a coma as has been pointed out by @MarcoVos in the comments to your question:

```
=CONCATENATE(B2," ",C2," ",D2," ",E2," ",F2," ",G2," ",H2)
```

Or if you want to use the more common form of & your formula would look like what you originally posted without the CONCATENATE out from like this:

```
=B2&" "&C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2&" "&G2&" "&H2
```

Those last two formulas will produce the same results.

2)  The INDIRECT function will convert text to a cell references or address.  It will not convert a formula as text and spit out the results of the formula.  Macros Vos in his answer is correct in that FORMULATEXT() will display the formula in the referenced cell as text or a string.  If you need to follow a sequence where you provide the string and then must convert the string into a formula, then I suggest you use the EVALUATE Function.  You cannot use EVALUATE from a regular excel formula though.  You can call it from a named range though.  Create a named range.  Lets for example call it EvalText.  In the formula portion for creating the named range, enter:

```
=EVALUATE($B$4)
```

It will automatically add the sheet name.  Now in any cell on your sheet you can enter:

```
=EvalText
```

and it will return whatever the string in B4 works out to be as a formula.  It will spit out an error if its not a proper excel formula.

Comment: one thing to take note of as i notice that the EVALUATE() in name range is not automatic calculation. it doesn't get updated automatically as the text changes. have to go to the cell and hit F2 Enter to update the value.

Comment: but nice idea, i like the solution

Comment: actually it should update automatically if your sheet is set to automatic update.

Comment: We don't have Evaluate function in recent Excel version any more in 2022

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it the other way around?

Put:

```
=TRIM(CONCATENATE(B2&" "&C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2&" "&G2&" "&H2))
```

in cell B6 and

```
=FORMULATEXT(B6)
```

in cell B4.

Comment: I apologize, I accidently did not provide the correct Text String located in Cell B4 here is the actual formula text: =CONCATENATE("=TRIM(CONCATENATE(B2&" "&C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2&" "&G2&" "&H2))")  that I need or would like converted to an actual formula that outputs the results in Cell B6... Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the named "Range" is that it is not part of the Recalc-Loop.
Defining (in VBA) a function

```
Function MyEval(text As String)
    MyEval = Evaluate(text)
End Function
```

and adding

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.CalculateFull
End Sub
```

to the codesheet of the worksheet under consideration
solves the problem.
Of course, the workbook than has t be saved as XLSM.